# How to print char **

Tags: c, pointers

I have a method that read the file and assign the lines to char **. But when I try to print its first element it prints random characters. What may be wrong?

```
int main()
{
     char **lines_from_file = read_from_file(file_name);
     print_first_line(lines_from_file);
     return 0;
}

void print_first_line(char **command_lines)
{
    printf("%s", command_lines[0]);
}

char** read_from_file(char *file_name)
{
    int size;
    int c;
    char *buffer;
    char** all_lines= (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(f)
    {
        int i=0;
        do   // read all lines in file
        {
            size = 0;
            buffer = (char *)malloc(size+1);
            do  // read one line
            {
                c = fgetc(f);
                if(c != EOF) buffer[size++] = (char)c;
                buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, size+1);
            }
            while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
                
            *(all_lines+i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
            **(all_lines+i) = *buffer;
            i++;
            all_lines = (char**)realloc(all_lines, sizeof(char*) * i);

        }
        while(c != EOF);
        fclose(f);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return all_lines;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` does not do what you expect; use your `size` variable there.  `**(all_lines+i) = *buffer;` copies just one `char`.

Comment: There is a lot of boundary condition errors. Try to stick to this pattern: `while (read_it(the_data) == ok) { process_it(the_data); }`. Avoid `do ... while`, it is rarely appropriate. If you have a line reading loop nested in a file reading loop, make the former a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

A problem is in the line:

```
        **(all_lines+i) = *buffer;
```

That copies just a single character from `buffer`. As a consequence, none of the strings in `all_lines` is null terminated.

You should replace the lines:

```
        *(all_lines+i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        **(all_lines+i) = *buffer;
```

by

```
        all_lines[i] = buffer;
```

**Problem 2**

The next problem I see is in the line:

```
        all_lines = (char**)realloc(all_lines, sizeof(char*) * i);
```

In the first iteration of the loop, `i` is 1. Hence, that line is the same as:

```
        all_lines = (char**)realloc(all_lines, sizeof(char*));
```

which is not what you want. You want

```
        all_lines = (char**)realloc(all_lines, sizeof(char*) * 2);
```

since you will be using `all_lines[1]` in the next iteration. That lines needs to be:

```
        all_lines = (char**)realloc(all_lines, sizeof(char*) * (i+1));
```

Comment: definitely.. I changed the code like you said and it prints the first line right. but now I can't print the second line, I wonder why?

Comment: the third problem was the line I'm freeing buffer as it is actually points the last line. I need to free after I finish my work. All good I can roll on! thanks